# API response is NULL in Node but works fine in Python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x

I have to utilize node for this project and it is returning as null.

```
'use strict';

var https = require('https');
var pathString = '/api/SomeAPI/Start?Query=SomeData&Account=USER\sean1234&needed=0';

var request = https.get({
host: "some-host-path",
path: pathString,
header: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
}, function(response) {

    var json = "";
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        json += chunk;
        console.log("json is: " + json);

     });
    response.on('end', function() {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(json);
        var count = 0;
        var reply = "";
        var keys;

        console.log("jsonData is: " +jsonData);
        console.log("Object.keys(jsonData) is: " + Object.keys(jsonData));
        console.log("Object.keys(jsonData[0]) is: " + Object.keys(jsonData[0]));
        //console.log("Object.keys(jsonData[0].SomeData is: " + Object.keys(jsonData[0].SomeData));
        //The previous line raises an Error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

        console.log("\njsonData[0].SomeData: " +jsonData[0].SomeData);

        count = jsonData[0].SomeData;

        console.log("JSON.stringify(count): " + JSON.stringify(count)); 
     });

});
```

The logs from above node.js code are as follows:

```
json is: [{"SomeData":null}]
jsonData is: [object Object]
Object.keys(jsonData) is: 0
Object.keys(jsonData[0]) is: SomeData

jsonData[0].SomeData: null
JSON.stringify(count): null
```

As you can see, they are returning as null but when I tried to access the same API this time with Python, it returned the correct value as expected:

```
import json
import requests

api_url = 'some-api-url'

response = requests.get(api_url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
print(response.status_code)
loaded = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
print(loaded)
```

logs from the above Python code:

```
200
[{'SomeData': 2893}]
```

I have no choice but to utilize node for this project. Did I miss something? What seems wrong here?

P.S. In case I did not make my point clear, I am using the exact same API for both Node and Python codes above.

Comment: According to [this example](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) you should be able to call `https.get('some_api_url', function(){...})`, instead of passing host and path

Comment: @barbsan I changed it to that format, still same API response.

Comment: Have you compared headers of those 2 queries?

Comment: @barbsan I haven't, how do I do that?

Comment: Do you run these projects only in console or some browser? Or you could add to js query header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` (I see it's set in python code but not in js)

Comment: @barbsan I'm using console to debug this API. I have added the header as you have suggested too, still same null output. I'll edit my original post to reflect this.

Comment: @brian3415 Can you please share the output of `JSON.stringify(jsonData)`, and what is the output of `jsonData[0]['SomeData']` and please log `chunk` value as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of the issue when I tried changing the parameters in the API pathString (due to security concerns, I cannot post the actual one here)

The API was something like this

```
pathString = '/api/SomeAPI/Start?Query=SomeData&Account=USER\sean1234&needed=0';
```

I tried different valid user account values for "Account" until I finally tested it with a user that stats with letter "b" thus the path is now something like:

```
pathString = '/api/SomeAPI/Start?Query=SomeData&Account=USER\brian3415&needed=0';
```

This pathString with \b started throwing an error:

> throw new TypeError('Request path contains unescaped characters');

To escape the unescaped character I doubled the "\" into "\\" thus the path:

```
pathString = '/api/SomeAPI/Start?Query=SomeData&Account=USER\\brian3415&needed=0';
```

With this, the error is no longer thrown + the API is finally returning the expected JSON with the correct integer.

What I find weird is that the API is still returning JSON with null value `[{"SomeData":null}]` rather than resulting in a complete error. And to make matters worse, I have another API with different parameters (change "SomeData" in the pathString into "SomeOtherData") which is actually working perectly - returns the correct `[{"SomeOtherData":123}]` - even with the unescaped "\".